# How to check boost thread is running and Kill it

Tags: c++, boost, window, boost-thread

In my program, it start a boost  thread and keep the handler as a member of the main thread.
When user press the cancel button I need to check the started thread still running and if it is running need tho kill that specific thread. here is the pseudo code.

cheating thread

```
int i =1;
boost::thread m_uploadThread = boost::thread(uploadFileThread,i);
```

This is the method use to check if thread is still running, **but it is not working**

```
boost::posix_time::time_duration timeout = boost::posix_time::milliseconds(2);
if (this->uploadThread.timed_join(timeout)){
 //Here it should kill the thread
}
```

Comment: what it this thread doing?

Comment: Never kill your threads, end them cooperatively.

Comment: Never kill your threads, end them cooperatively. (that comment needed some concurrency)

Comment: @SamMiller : This thread doing some file printing to printer.

Comment: @Yakk/@ Branko Dimitrijevic : So instead of kill, How to end?

Comment: Threads should be listening for signals telling them to "nevermind what you are doing, just finish up", and then obeying them once they notice it.  Killing a thread causes undefined behavior in practice.  The thread could continue execution after being told to die, and the controlling code needs to handle that possibility gracefully.  In general, working with threading primitives at this level takes lots of care, and you should be comfortable with formal proofs of correctness of threading operations.

Comment: @Yakk: Thank you so much for your guidance.+1. Do you have any idea about good reading material related to this contest of the threads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value true means the thread is completed before the call times out. And looks like what you want is

```
if(!this->uploadThread.timed_join(timeout))
```

Comment: Thank you for the point +1. Do you have any idea how to end thread if still runing?

Comment: Generally you don't kill a thread but notify it to end its life. I agree with Yakk in the upper comment.

Comment: I want to see if a thread is running so I don't try to start a second one -- and I don't want to keep a sidebar variable around. You'd think there'd be an api to discover if a boost::thread is not-a-thread...

Answer (score 2):

For stop your thread you can use:

```
my_thread.interrupt();
```

in order this to work you have to set an [interruption point](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.interruption.predefined_interruption_points) at the point you want the thread's function stops when you interrupt.

*Note: the interruption by it self don't stop the thread it just set a flag and the when an interruption point is reached the thread is interrupted. If no interruption point is found, the thread don't stop.*

You can also handle the interrupted exception `boost::thread_interrupted` that way you can do things depending on if the thread was interrupted or not.

For instance lets assume the next code is inside a thread function:

```
try
{
    //... some important code here
    boost::this_thread.interruption_poit(); // Setting interrutption point.
}
catch(boost::thread_interrupted&)
{
    // Now you do what ever you want to do when 
    // the thread is interrupted.
}
```